# UIViewControllers being reused in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageVIewController` and I am initialising the controllers inside using the reuse identifier i.e:

```
BaseContentViewController *contentViewController = (BaseContentViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:self.controllerRestorationIDs[index]];
```

I have noticed that

> if a `UIViewController` is reused then `viewDidLoad` is not called in that controller so any code that I want to be executed every single time the `UIViewController` appears won't.

For example I want to change the background color each time it appears.

Is there some method like the `prepareForReuse` that `UITableViewCell` has that I can put this code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it in -viewWillAppear:.

Comment: From my experimentation it seems pretty random if a new view controller is created or if it uses one that is stored in the memory. Is this just some auto memory management feature? I guess if I want to do something every single time it appears I should put the code in viewWillAppear then?

Comment: It's my understanding (and experience) that -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: will create a new instance each time it's called. I'd start with the assumption that that is what it's doing, and what you're seeing is actually some other misunderstanding of the code you've written.

Comment: If this happened viewDidLoad would be called each time though, no? I put a NSLog in this to check. Sometimes it is called and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Yes, I would expect -viewDidLoad to be called every time.

Comment: It's not. If you are using "reuse" identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method like the prepareForReuse,it is `-viewWillAppear:` :
If you want change the background color each time the `ViewController` appears,you can `setBackgroudColor` like :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.f
                                                    green:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.f
                                                     blue:arc4random_uniform(256)/255.f alpha:1.f
                                ];
}
```